# Why does touch create new files?

Tags: files, touch

I am aware that the `touch` command is used to update the date of last modification on a file. It is also used to create a new file if requested file does not exist on file system.

Since touch (as it's name implies), should just update last mod date, why does it also try to create a new file?

Is it just a check written in the touch's code, or is it something else that causes a file to be created?

Comment: As a usage case, I use `touch /forcefsck` to create an empty file called `/forcefsck` to force file systems to be checked for errors on the next reboot. The file itself doesn't need to contain anything, it just needs to exist. Without `touch`, I'd need to use `vi` or `nano` to save a blank file. Much quicker to use `touch`.

Comment: @Tim There's no real reason you couldn't use `>/forcefsck` or `printf '' >>/forcefsck` (the latter would preserve any existing contents). What you describe is a way to use a utility that works in a certain way, but that has no real bearing on why it's written to work that way.

Comment: If this question is about the design of `touch` rather than how it works, I think `touch` violates the Single Responsibility Principle with the file creation side effect. Therefore, the "why" is simply due to early design choices that got stuck due to popularity and prevalence/ease of use.

Answer (score 17):

`touch` creates a new, empty file if the file doesn't exist because that's what it was designed to do. The utility has to contain code to handle that case specifically. The utility appeared in [Unix V7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_7_Unix); its [manual](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/man/man1/touch.1) described it thus:

> touch — update date last modified of a file
>
> `touch` attempts to set the modified date of each *file*. 
>   This is done by reading a character from the file and writing it back.
>   If a **file* does not exist, an attempt will be made to create it unless the `-c` option is specified.

(I don't know what `touch` did if the file was empty. The [underlying system call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xsh/utime.html) came later.)

I don't know for sure why `touch` was designed to make the file exist, but I suspect it's because of [`make`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)). Why would you want to set a file's modification time to the current time? There are cases where it could be useful to set the modification time to a particular time, but that ability came later, the original `touch` could only set the modification time to the current time. A reason to do that is to re-run a `make` rule that depends on the file.

That is, suppose you have a file `foo`, and a makefile that declares a command to generate `bar` from `foo`. When you type `make bar`, the command is executed and `bar` is created. If `bar` exists and is newer than `foo`, `make bar` does nothing, because `make` assumes that `bar` has already been generated. However, if `bar` is older than `foo`, make thinks that `bar` is not up-to-date and needs to be regenerated.

But what if the rules to generate `bar` have changed? Then you have two options:

- `rm bar; make bar`
- `touch foo; make bar`

You would need `foo` to exist in order to generate `bar`, otherwise the command would typically not work.

The “touch” terminology was also present in the [`make`](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/man/man1/make.1) utility: `make -t bar` would only pretend to run the commands, that is, it would set the modification time of `bar` to the current time without actually running the command to generate `bar` (you would do this if you thought that the changes to `foo` shouldn't affect `bar`). The `touch` utility was therefore a standalone version of the `make -t` feature.

Answer (score 15):

Using `strace touch t` yields:

```
open("t", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = 3
```

It is in `touch`'s code and I wouldn't call it a *check* though. 
The timestamp is updated by opening the file for writing and then just closing it.